# Access remote Glassfish server from appclient

Tags: glassfish

I have two Glassfish 3.1.2 server on different machines(localhost and 192.168.0.5). I also have an appclient client application that calls EJBs and gets messages from JMS queues. I have to use appclient container since this is the only option I have if I want to use transacted session to JMS queue.

If I run appclient on localhost via appclient.bat script I have to provide targetserver parameter to the script like this:
appclient.bat -targetserver localhost -jar appClient.jar -clientArg1 -clientArg2

This makes the appclient connect to Glassfish running on the localhost. Now I want to connect to the Glassfish on 192.168.0.5 in my client java application while appclient is conencted to locahost.

I've tried setting parameters to InitialContext, but they are not taken.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", sourceURL);
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
```

The references to EJBs, JMS queues, ... are always taken from the Glassfish server specified by the targetserver parameter.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution, so I'm running appclient batch file with targetserver parameter as many times as I have to.

Comment: you run the client on each machine, passing `localhost`?  or, you run it remotely, passing an ip address?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Since 2012 I've done something different. Now I'm using direct connection to the queue manager, so I've stopped using appcllient. If I want to do a call to the server I use JAX-RS or JAX-WS.